# problems with sizing formatting text into a listbox

Tags: c#, text, listbox

all right so im having difficulties will all my .text output to fit into the listbox line its assigned to is there any way to get the text to not go further than the width of the list box?

this is how i got

```
private void btnCompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string accessories = ""
    if (chkChildSeat.Checked) 
    {
        accessories = accessories + chkChildSeat.Text+",";
    }
    if (chkLockHelmet.Checked)
    {
        accessories = accessories + chkLockHelmet.Text+",";
    }
    if (chkTrailer.Checked) 
    {
        accessories=accessories+chkTrailer.Text;
    }
    lstInvoice.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,-49}{1,-14}", "Invoice Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("d")));
    lstInvoice.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,-50}{1,-13}", Customername, CustomerID));
    lstInvoice.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,-49}{1,-14}", "Rental Date", dateTimePicker1.Value));
    lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,-25}{1,-28}", "Accessories", accessories.ToString()));
    lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,-49}{1,-14}", "Total Invoice Amount", result.ToString("c")));
}
```

this will display the static sized text like the date and time, but will cut off some text that changes with user interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen an example on code project whereby an ellipsis is included for overflowing text.
It seems like it is something that would help you:

[Auto-Ellipsis](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37503/Auto-Ellipsis)

(The TextBox class is extended to create a text box control that shortens text to fit, along with other controls too).

I think inspecting this will be a good start for implementing it in ListBox

Comment: could this work with a list box class inside a form?